# How do I resize a UIView and force its subviews to resize without Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

What would be the best way to resize a view and all of it's subviews at the same time, so that the aspect ratio of everything is kept the same? And all without autolayout.

I'm trying to do this based on the content offset of a `UIScrollview`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);
   // Resize view here
}
```

The problem is if I just make the frame of the view smaller, none of the subviews get resized obviously.

Comment: if you dont want to use autolayout then you need to change  the frame of every view and its subviews.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri using a for loop? Is there some clever way to do this?

Comment: IF the frame of subviews are desgined to resize according to their superview, then you can change the superview frame to adjust all the view frames

Comment: for example one subviewframe as (x+20,y+40,w-100,h-100), and the superView frame being (x,y,w,h), then you can just change the superview frame.

Comment: Just recalculate layout in layoutSubviews

Comment: @Andy yeah the specific problem we're running into is that we have a `UILabel` with several lines of text, and we want to resize that label so it gets smaller but none of the words switch lines. So the frame of the label and font will have to change accordingly. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Apollo you probably have to specify `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for label.